# How to get the input from other's file stdout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream, stdio

For example,

I have this snippet of code in a file (let's say it's called **main.js**) :

```
function main(){

    console.log(5);
}
```

And I have another file in which I want to get the stdout from **main.js**.

My current code is :

```
var readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
input : fs.createReadStream("./src/main.js",{encoding: "utf8"}),
output: process.stdout,
terminal: false
})   


rl.on('line',parseCB)
function parseCB (line) {
      process.stdout.write(line+'\n')  //<--- what you expect rl.write to do.
}
```

But the problem is that createReadStream get's the whole file content. How could I only get the *stdout* from **main.js** as the input in the second file?

Comment: what do you mean by stdout? do you want to invoke the script using node script.js and then fetch the stout in another file?

Answer (score 1):

To get your script to output on stdout you need to execute it somehow. Your first problem though is that executing main.js as it is won't actually output anything. You define `main()` but you need to explicitly call the function somewhere like:

```
function main(){

    console.log(5);
}

main();
```

Now if you run `node main.js` you get the expected `5` on stdout.

Here are two options to access that output in another script.

**Option 1: execute main.js as a child process of script.js**

```
//script.js

const { exec } = require('child_process');
const child = exec('node main.js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  process.stdout.write('Executed main.js and got: ' + stdout)
});
```

Running `node script.js` will output: `Executed main.js and got: 5`

**Option 2: Execute main.js and pipe its output to script.js**

```
//script.js

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(`Read line: ${line}`);
});
```

Running `node main.js | node script.js` will output: `Read line: 5`